# JavaScript Word API adding Comment changes formatting

Tags: javascript, comments, word-addins

I have created a word addin for data annotation. It allows the customer to select a piece of data and enter a comment in the addin input box. It basically uses Javascript to add comments.xml package part, relationship and the comment reference in the word xml. Finally when i do `setSelectedDataAsync`, the comment adds fine but the numbering of elements changes.

The cause seems to be the `pPr` `numPr` which changes from

```
<w:p w14:paraId="16364ACD" w14:textId="2CDE0004" w:rsidR="00676203" w:rsidRDefault="00573A57" w:rsidP="00510DD8">
    <w:pPr>
        <w:pStyle w:val="ListParagraph"/>
        <w:numPr>
            <w:ilvl w:val="0"/>
            <w:numId w:val="2"/>
        </w:numPr>
        <w:rPr>
        <w:lang w:val="en-US"/>
        </w:rPr>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:lang w:val="en-US"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>Testing</w:t>
    </w:r>
</w:p>
```

to

```
<w:p w14:paraId="00364AE3" w14:textId="D2DE0005" w:rsidR="4567620A" w:rsidRDefault="35473A57" w:rsidP="066516D9">
    <w:pPr>
        <w:pStyle w:val="ListParagraph"/>
        <w:numPr>
            <w:ilvl w:val="0"/>
            <w:numId w:val="4"/>
        </w:numPr>
        <w:rPr>
        <w:lang w:val="en-US"/>
        </w:rPr>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:commentRangeStart w:id="0"/>
    <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:lang w:val="en-US"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>Testing</w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:commentRangeEnd w:id="0"/>
    <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:rStyle w:val="CommentReference"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:commentReference w:id="0"/>
    </w:r>
</w:p>
```

I have tried almost everything and am yet stuck with the bug.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. Basically, the setAsync method edits the numbering package. setting it to the previous numbering, fixes the formatting issue

Comment: Providing the code you've used and marking your answer as accepted may help others to find and understand yours easier.